# Error:(1, 1) Unable to execute Clang-Tidy: clazy-standalone is not found or cannot be executed in AndroidStudio

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, java-native-interface, clang

In my AndroidStudio project I created native library using JNI with CMake and CPP code. Everything builds and runs OK, but when I try to commit and push my code to git, the CodeAnalysis appears in the "Messages" bottom tab, showing me an error:

```
Error:(1, 1) Unable to execute Clang-Tidy: clazy-standalone is not found or cannot be executed
```

In **Preferences -> Other settings -> Clang-Tidy** I see "Built-in Clang-Tidy version: 13.0.0" and an option to "Use external Clang-Tidy instead of the built-in one" (which is not set)

Could you please tell me where to find the settings of clazy-standalone (to set it) and/or at least to suppress the error message?

I am a newbie in C/CPP programming, writing mostly in kotlin/Java

P.S. I use MacBook Pro with MacOS BigSur 11.6.1 and AndroidStudio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Beta 5

Comment: *I am a newbie in C/CPP programming*. Terminology note: C and C++ are different languages. People lump them together all the time, but don't be fooled. Having a good formatter/linter/whatever for one does not mean you have an effective tool for both.

Comment: did you find an answer? I have the exact same case

Comment: Well C++ is an extension on top of C and so is Swift when you program in IOS and quite some other programming languages. In general, it means that C-code can usually be written directly in the code. In Java the JNI is a C-piggyback with a communications interface. Note that Java and C have completely different memory allocation systems (how memory is allocated and freed) while C++ and swift has a basic C foundation with add-ons and can’t be directly mixed.

Comment: However, the Java and C syntax is very similar, the code can’t be mixed directly. You need to be aware of the difference in syntax and memory management when you start working with a new language, the prime topics. And sometimes the applied libraries in C++ like the MFC can be called with a C-syntax (often not displayed but usually possible). Topics to look into for an experienced newcomer to a language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This came from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218346038

---

This happens because Android Studio does not support `clazy`, but the option is still shipped in the settings menu, and in this case, it seems to be enabled.

When `clang-tidy via clangd` is enabled, there is nothing to do.

When `clang-tidy via clangd` is disabled, then

- If `clazy` is enabled, this error will be observed.

To disable `clazy`, go to: `Settings > Editor > Inspections > C++` and uncheck `clazy`.

---

Note for Android Studio devs: We should check if we can disable this clazy feature in Android Studio. It seems to be a tool specific to some qt framework.

Comment: Will this settings effect to step-by-step debug in c++?

Answer (score 27):

This also happened to me when I updated from Android Studio Arctic Fox to Bumblebee.

What fixed it for me:
Go to `Preferences` → `Clangd` and enable `Use clang-tidy via clangd` (also enables some `CLion builtin inspections`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I rechecked the mentioned setting and tried to play with other on Preferences -> Other settings -> Clangd, but none of them seems to solve my problem

Comment: Can you try opening Android Studio from the terminal and see if that fixes the problem?

Run this command in terminal:
`/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`

Comment: I've tried '/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio'  - this command starts Android Studio instance, yes, but not solves the Clang-Tidy issue

Comment: Thank you. That actually worked for me. The error banner vanished after applying this suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

I have two kinds of errors

Preferences -> Other settings

1. -> Clang-Tidy

   disable `Use external clang-tidy instead of built-in one:`

   Solved `Unable to execute Clang-Tidy: clang-Tidy is not found or cannot be executed`
2. -> Clanger

   enable `Use clang-tidy via clangd`

   Solved `Unable to execute Clang-Tidy: clazy-standalone is not found or cannot be executed`